# Display image captured from Popcorn.js on body

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, html5-video, popcornjs

js to load a video, this is fine.

I'm using [Popcorn Capture](https://github.com/rwaldron/popcorn.capture) to capture the current frame, copy it into an image which is attached to the body. This appears to be working.  An image of the frame shows, and pauses.

What I want to happen is to keep this image at the top level, do some stuff underneath and then fade this image away when ready for a nice transition.

What I get is

- image shows
- layer underneath renders
- video starts again above new rendered layer, unless I remove the video with jQuery which removes the image as well.

I can't seem to even destroy/get rid of video without removing the image.

Here's the code

```
    image = document.createElement("image");
    image.id = "capture";
    image.setAttribute("class", "video-js");


    img = currentVideo.pause().currentTime( 0 ).capture({
            target: "img#capture",
            media: true
    });


    image.src = img;
    document.body.appendChild(image);


    $("#capture").fadeTo("slow" , 0);
    currentVideo.src = '';
    currentVideo.load();
    currentVideo.destroy();

    videoPlaying = false;
    createScene();

    $('#video').remove();
    $('#prevButton').show();
    $('#openGuide').show();
    $('#openSceneInfo').show();
```

Any clues on how to make sure that image stays on screen, and then can be faded away?

Answer (score 0):

Just faded out the video element with fadeTo. This worked better.